# Trying to find distinct values in an NSArrayMutableArray using containsObject

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com as a backend on an app I am developing.  Parse.com is not able to return unique results via a PFQuery.  What I am doing is retrieving a PFQuery of all golf rounds of a user and then trying to get determine the unique courses that user has played.  The unique courses should have a unique combination of the following attributes:

- Course name
- Course Tee (color of tee played)
- Course Rating
- Course Slope

Here is my code:

```
 PFQuery *courseQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Rounds"];
    [courseQuery selectKeys:@[@"roundUser",@"roundCourse",@"roundTee", @"roundRating",@"roundSlope",]];
    [courseQuery whereKey:@"roundUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];
    [courseQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *courseObjects,NSError *error){
        if(!error)
        {
            NSMutableArray* coursesFromParseNonUnique=[courseObjects mutableCopy];
            NSMutableArray *coursesFromParseUnique=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            int x;
            for (x=1;x<=courseObjects.count;x++)
            {
                NSObject *currentObject = [coursesFromParseNonUnique lastObject];
                NSLog(@"Object %d : %@",x,currentObject);
                if (![coursesFromParseUnique containsObject:currentObject])
                {
                    [coursesFromParseUnique addObject:currentObject];
                }
                [coursesFromParseNonUnique removeLastObject];
            }

        }
        else NSLog(@"failed");
    }
```

Any ideas on why this is not returning a unique set of courses based on the 4 characteristics stated above?

Comment: It means that there are no duplicate objects in coursesFromParseNonUnique array, containsObject just checks the object pointer and not its properties. Please include a sample of output that you are getting now and the expected output.

Comment: @Suhas You are incorrect. `containsObject:` calls the `isEqual:` method on each object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your result looks like `PFObject` is not implementing `isEqual:` and so gets the default implementation from `NSObject` - which is identity (an object is equal to itself and nothing else).

Google turns up [this](https://parse.com/questions/ios-implement-isequal-on-pfobject) which supports that theory.

You can take the same approach as in that reference: use a category to add `isEqual:` and `hash`, making your method compare for equality the four attributes.

If you're stuck over `isEqual:` & `hash` follow the Mike Ash link in the above reference.

HTH.

Comment: So if I understand correctly my method is saying that all of my values are unique because they have unique pointers . . . So I need to go a little deeper using a hash in order to determine if the attributes of the object are equal.  Is that correct?  I will try this when I get home this evening.  Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Is there any help you could provide me with using hash?  I'm teaching myself Objective-C from scratch so any straight forward advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Follow the link to the Mike Ash article in the above referenced page that Google turned up. You need to implement `isEqual:` - which does 5 tests, checks the class of the argument and the equality of your 4 attributes - and `hash` - which combines the hashes of your 4 attributes.